# Can't create table (errno: 150) on FOREIGN KEY

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreign-keys, errno

I saw a lot of same question but I couldn't solve my case.

If I run this code:

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config.php');

$servername = HOST;
$username = USERNAME;
$password = PASSWORD;
$dbname = DB;

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Articls (
            id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,     
            name VARCHAR(254) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL      
) DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table Articls created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Tags (
            id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
            id_articls INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,   
            name VARCHAR(256) COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,           
            FOREIGN KEY(Tags.id_articls) REFERENCES Articls(Articls.id)         
) DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_persian_ci";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table Tags created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I get this error: ( If I remove FOREIGN KEY it works)

> Table Articls created successfully Error creating table: Can't create
>   table 'admin_wepar.Tags' (errno: 150)

**Edit**

If a change `into Articls.id` and `Tags.id_articls` I got this error:

> Table Articls created successfullyError creating table: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FOREIGN KEY
>   (Tags.id_articls) REFERENCES Articls(Articls.id) ) DEFAULT COLLA' at
>   line 5

Comment: Your first create table statement would fail, because of the comma on the second line.

Comment: You are right but the orginal code is true...I also corrected here

Comment: You are also using `create table if not exists`, so you do not know if the table is really being created.  Try dropping the table and running the code again.

Answer (score 0):

`Tags.id_articls` is a *signed* integer while `Articl.id` is an *unsigned* integer. MySQL requires referencing field to be exactly the same type. Make `Tags.id_articls` unsigned to have it work.

Additionally, the table names in the column lists are not allowed in MySQL. It is always clear which table is meant: first the *referencing* table and then the *referenced* table. So change

```
FOREIGN KEY(Tags.id_articls) REFERENCES Articls(Articls.id)
```

into

```
FOREIGN KEY(id_articls) REFERENCES Articls(id)
```

and it will work.

Comment: I changed the code to "id_articls INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL," but I get last error (check my edited question"

Comment: @aliraha: I updated my answer to solve the remaining problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare both `Articls.id` and `Tags.id_articls` signed or unsigned

Comment: I changd it but I get last error (check my edited question" pls

Comment: Beats me, I copy pasted your sql code into mysql (except for making id_articls unsigned) and it worked for me.

Comment: You should edit your question so it contains the correct type for  id_articls.

Comment: I change the source (Edited question) and copy/paste..I get same error